# UIImage is not loading after URLSession Data Task

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mapkit, nsurlsession

I'm having a hard time with an image download. I'm using an image URL from Firebase to download a jpeg, and using the image in a map view callout. Currently, the callout appears at the correct size but with no image or subtitle. It works perfectly when I pass in an image asset manually. The image URL is saved perfectly to the newDog object. When I debug and inspect the image, it appears in memory but looks empty.

I think maybe this has something to do with loading the callout views before the image download has completed?

Here's my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.map.mapType = .standard
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    self.map.userTrackingMode = .follow
    self.map.delegate = self
    self.map.mapType = .hybrid
    let userDogRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("dogs")

    userDogRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value == nil {
            print("no new dog found")
        } else {
            print("new dog found")

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
            let dogID = snapshotValue["dogID"]!

            let dogRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("dogs").child(dogID)
            dogRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                print("Found dog data!")
                let value = snap.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

                let name = value["name"]!
                let breed = value["breed"]!
                let creator = value["creator"]!
                let score = Int(value["score"]!)!
                let lat = Double(value["latitude"]!)!
                let lon = Double(value["longitude"]!)!
                let url = value["imageURL"]!
                let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)

                let newDog = Dog()
                newDog.name = name
                newDog.breed = breed
                newDog.creator = creator
                newDog.score = score
                newDog.imageURL = url
                newDog.location = location

                let downloadURL = URL(string: newDog.imageURL)!
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    newDog.picture = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.dogs.append(newDog)
                    let annotation  = CustomAnnotation(location: newDog.location, title: newDog.name, subtitle: newDog.creator)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
                    }

                }).resume()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Here's my mapview and annotation methods:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if(annotation is MKUserLocation){
        return nil
    }

    let ident = "pin"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: ident)
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: ident)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    configureDetailView(annotationView!)
    return annotationView
}

func configureDetailView(_ annotationView: MKAnnotationView) {
    let width = 300
    let height = 300

    let dogPhotoView = UIView()
    let views = ["dogPhotoView": dogPhotoView]
    dogPhotoView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[dogPhotoView(\(height))]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    dogPhotoView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[dogPhotoView(\(width))]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))


    for dog in self.dogs {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        imageView.image = dog.picture
    }

    annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = dogPhotoView
}
```

I'm using a custom annotation class. Here's that:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.coordinate = location
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = title
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here's a photo of my debugger:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurred when I was constructing the callout image view. I created an imageView, but I didn't ever add it as a subview of it's superview. What a silly oversight! Here's the correct code:

```
func configureDetailView(_ annotationView: MKAnnotationView) {
    let width = 300
    let height = 300

    let dogPhotoView = UIView()
    let views = ["dogPhotoView": dogPhotoView]
    dogPhotoView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[dogPhotoView(\(height))]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    dogPhotoView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[dogPhotoView(\(width))]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))


    for dog in self.dogs {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        imageView.image = dog.picture

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            dogPhotoView.addSubview(imageView)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }

    annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = dogPhotoView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataTask` works asynchronously. You should move to code to create the annotation in the completion handler.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    newDog.picture = UIImage(data: data!)!
    self.dogs.append(newDog)
    let annotation  = CustomAnnotation(location: newDog.location, title: newDog.name, subtitle: newDog.creator)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}).resume()
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting the same result. Please take a look at my edited code. @vadian

Comment: Don't edit the code applying suggestions. It confuses others who are trying to help

Comment: I appreciate that, I hadn't thought about that before.

Answer (score 0):

Move `self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)` to URLSession.shared.dataTask completion handler. Currently picture is set to Dog object after map adds annotation. Don't forget to wrap addAnnotation(_:) call with `OperationQueue.main.addOperation`.